# valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm getting the error

> Thread 1: "[<MyProject.VisitorModel 0x60000290e840> valueForUndefinedKey:]:
> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name."

VisitorModel looks like this:

```
@objcMembers
class VisitorModel : NSObject {
    dynamic var visitorName: String?
    dynamic var visitorPhoneNumber: String?
    dynamic var visitorCountryCode: String?
    dynamic var visitorCompany: String?
    dynamic var visitDate: String?
    dynamic var visitorHost: String?

    init(visitorName : String?, visitorPhoneNumber : String?, visitorCountryCode : String?, visitorCompany: String?, visitDate: String?, visitorHost: String?) {
        self.visitorName = visitorName
        self.visitorPhoneNumber = visitorPhoneNumber
        self.visitorCountryCode = visitorCountryCode
        self.visitorCompany = visitorCompany
        self.visitDate = visitDate
        self.visitorHost = visitorHost
        }
}
```

The key `name` was in the `VisitorModel` by mistake earlier, but it's no where to be found now..  How kan I correct this error?

Comment: `dynamic var`iables are used for Cocoa Bindings. Likely there is a dead binding. And why do you make it worse by adding all the ugly redundant `visitor` parts to the property names? The naming guidelines suggest `class Visitor ... var name ... var phoneNumber`

Comment: @vadian There was a dead binding. And you're right. I thought it was easier to identify the different properties by adding visitor, but it just got confusing. It's all sorted now